# Math.tan for small angles. Does python use small angle approximation?

Tags: python, math, floating-point, precision

I am trying to compute `math.tan(0.000000001)` and I am getting 0.00000001

```
>>> math.tan(0.00000001) == 0.00000001
True
```

Is this due to how math.tan is implemented? Does it use [small-angle approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_approximation)?

Where can I get more documentation about this

Comment: What result did you expect? [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan%280.00000001%29) gives the same result (with regards to the available precision)

Comment: That's because `tan(x)` where `x -> 0` is equal to `x`. This is true regardless of how you calculate `tan`. Python floats don't have enough precision to know that `math.tan(0.000000001)` is not `0.00000001`

Comment: Thank you, looks like we need more precision then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to go would be, by analogy with numpy.expm1, to implement a function that computes tan(x)-x in double precision.

While a production quality version of that night be tricky, here is a simple version, that should give accurate answers for |x| < 1e-6

```
tan(x)-x = sin(x)/cos(x) - x = (sin(x)-x*cos(x))/cos(x)
```

for such small x we can write, to better than double precision

```
sin(x) = x - x*x*x/6 + x*x*x*x*x/120
cos(x) = 1 - x*x/2 + x*x*x*x/24
```

Substituting these we get

```
tan(x)-x = x*x*x*(1.0/3 - (1.0/30)*x*x)/cos(x)
```

Comment: And this comes from Maclaurin series right? I will try this

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special about this. Python's `float` only has limited precision, which we can explore with numpy:

```
0.000000010000000000000000209226 # np.tan(0.00000001)

0.000000009999999999999998554864 # np.nextafter(np.tan(0.00000001), -1)
0.000000010000000000000001863587 # np.nextafter(np.tan(0.00000001), 1)

0.000000010000000000000000333... # True value
```

From this we can see that `0.000000010000000000000000209226` is the closest representation to the true value, but also that it's safe to round-trip this to `0.00000001`, thus Python chooses to print it that way.

Comment: I guess my unofficial follow up question then is. How would I go about computing this number? any hints?

Comment: @Davo Are you looking for an algorithmic answer ('how do I compute `tan(x)` up to `N` bits of precision), or a practical one (what tool allows me to do arbitrary precision arithmetic)?

Comment: It would probably be an algorithmic answer. I am looking at `mpmath` https://mpmath.org
I think I can find an answer there

Comment: `float precision ends roughly here` -- that isn't right; floating point numbers are closer together near 0 than near 1 (where the distance between successive floats is approximately 10^(-16)). For the example given, the pointer should be at the 3 or the one before it (can't tell right now).

Comment: @RobertDodier You are right of course, I updated my answer.